# Regular expression tricks in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a lines in file as:

> ```
> keyword = NORTH FACE
> keyword = GUESS
> keyword = DRESSES
> keyword = RALPH LAUREN
> ```

My Code is:

```
keyword=re.findall(r'ke\w+ = \S+',s).
```

This prints only

> ```
> NORTH
> GUESS
> DRESSES
> RALPH
> ```

But I need regex to handle and print

```
NORTH FACE
GUESS
DRESSES
RALPH LAUREN
```

Comment: How are you reading the lines? Do you only read one line at a time? Will there ever be more than one "keyword=value" pair on each line?

Comment: Just `.*` after the `= ` works. [Example](http://regexr.com?2vai1)

Comment: `I have a lines in file as`... That is 4 lines as I count it...

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is consuming non whitespace characters only (`\S`). That is why it stops matching when it encounters a space character.

Change that to `.*`. This will greedily match all characters except newlines (`\n`).

Comment: @ridgerunner: Hmm, the one time I don't test my regex :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r'ke\w+ = .+$', s)
```

Or this, to capture only what's after the equals sign:

```
re.findall(r'ke\w+ = (.+)$', s)
```

Comment: I need to capture after = xxxx xxxx and sometimes = xxxx

Comment: I did that it doesnt print any

Comment: In your problem description, what's exactly `s` ? I assumed it was one line, like this: `s = 'keyword = NORTH FACE'` . Also, `findall` returns a list, if you only need the string, we can extract it adding `[0]` afterwards

Comment: s is the input file that has keyword = NORTH FACE    score = 88466 and some times keyword = NORTH     score = 88466 , I need both NORTH and NORTH FACE to be captured in different lines. Currently it captures first word after equals to

Comment: If `s` is a _file_ it won't work with `findall`. Perhaps you should edit your question and show us exactly what's the format of the file and the code that you're using for reading it

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `keyword=re.findall(r'ke\w+ = \S.*',s)` instead of `keyword=re.findall(r'ke\w+ = \S+',s)`.

Also, not sure if it serves what you want but following your example you could also do `re.split` as following:

```
>>> s = 'keyword = NORTH FACE'
>>> re.split(' = ', s)
['keyword', 'NORTH FACE']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex.  Try [partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) or [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
lines = '''\
keyword = NORTH FACE
keyword = GUESS
keyword = DRESSES
keyword = RALPH LAUREN
'''.splitlines()

for line in lines:
    line.partition(' = ')[2]
print
for line in lines:
    print line.split(' = ')[1]
```

#### Output

```
NORTH FACE
GUESS
DRESSES
RALPH LAUREN

NORTH FACE
GUESS
DRESSES
RALPH LAUREN
```

## Update

Given the new information in the comment and making a guess as to the datafile format (Update the question with a REAL example!):

```
import re

data = '''\
keyword = NORTH FACE
score = 88466
normalizedKeyword = NORTH FACE

keyword = DRESSES
score = 79379
normalizedKeyword = DRESSES
'''

L = re.findall(r'keyword = (.*)\nscore = (.*)\n',data)
for i in L:
    print ','.join(i)
```

#### Output

```
NORTH FACE,88466
DRESSES,79379
```

Comment: import re
with open('d:\log.txt') as f:
    file = open("d:\out.csv","w")
    s = f.read()
keyword=re.findall(r'ke\w+ = \S+',s)
score=re.findall(r'sc\w+ = \S+',s)
def after_equals(s):
    return s.partition(' = ')[-1]
for k,s in zip(keyword, score):
  file.write('%s,%s\n' %(after_equals(k), after_equals(s)))
file.close()
print "Export completed"
 and my file has lines (keyword = NORTH FACE    score = 88466    normalizedKeyword = NORTH FACE    productIds = [] ). The existing code outputs only NORTH,88466 but I need NORTH FACE,88466

Comment: The lines in the file are different like keyword = NORTH FACE    score = 88466    normalizedKeyword = NORTH FACE , keyword = DRESSES    score = 79379    normalizedKeyword = DRESSES. I need the output like NORTH FACE,88466 next line DRESSES,73379

Comment: @Ryder edit your question with this information and format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> s="""
... keyword = NORTH FACE
... keyword = GUESS
... keyword = DRESSES
... keyword = RALPH LAUREN
... """
>>> re.findall(r'ke\w+ = .*',s)
['keyword = NORTH FACE', 'keyword = GUESS', 'keyword = DRESSES', 'keyword = RALPH LAUREN']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you seek ...

From one of your comments, if you have adjacent lines that you want the values to pair up, but may be surrounded by non-paired lines, you have to do a few things.

1. Read the entire file into a buffer. This is because the paired lines can be anywhere in the file.
2. Treat the string as a single line.
3. Globally capture the values. In the below example, capture buffer 1 will be the 'keyword' value, capture buffer 2 will be the 'score' value. The 'keyword' and 'score' are placeholders for the real constants you wish pairs of values to be found for.

Expanded regex:
`(?:^|\n) [^\S\n]*`
`(?:keyword) [^\S\n]* = [^\S\n]* (\w(?:[^\S\n]*\w+)*) [^\S\n]* \n`
`\s*`
`(?:score)   [^\S\n]* = [^\S\n]* (\w(?:[^\S\n]*\w+)*) [^\S\n]*`
`(?=\n|$)`

Answer (score 0):

```
D = "keyword = RALPH LAUREN"
m = re.search('(?<== )(\w+\s*)*', D)  # search for anything after '= '
m.group(0)
'RALPH LAUREN'
C = "keyword = GUESS"
m.group(0)
'GUESS'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
msg=fh.read()
output=re.findall("keyword =(.*)",msg)
print (output)
```

Comment: How is this different from [Regular expression tricks in python](//stackoverflow.com/a/8291076) (apart from including the space between `=` and the matched keyword)?